# Is there a pair of functions solving this "trigonometric-like" system of ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

The (ordinary) trigonometric functions are the solutions to the system of ordinary differential equations:
\begin{align}
c' &= -as, \\
s' &= ac,
\end{align}
with $c(0) = 1$ and $s(0) = 0$, for some constant $a$. Similarly, the hyperbolic functions are the solutions to the system
\begin{align}
c' &= as, \\
s' &= ac,
\end{align}
with the same initial conditions. Is there similarly some pair of functions satisfying
\begin{align}
c' &= \bar{z}s, \\
s' &= zc,
\end{align}
again with the same initial conditions, and where $z$ is complex and $\bar{z}$ is the complex conjugate of $z$?

I have tried combining the trigonometric and hyperbolic functions in various ways, but cannot find a solution. If such a pair of functions does not exist, is there a method of finding e.g. a series solution?

Comment: Formulate your problem in state-space form, and compute the matrix exponential. I would imagine that the solution should have hyperbolic functions. If you need help with the state-space form, just tell me and I can develop that in the answers.

Comment: Hint: observe that $c''-|z|^2c=0$.

Comment: You probably mean the first to be
$$\begin{align}
c' &= -as, \\
s' &= ac,
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

So, we start with the system

$c' = \bar zs, \tag 1$

$s' = z c, \tag 2$

with $z \in \Bbb C$ a constant.  We differentiate (1) and obtain

$c'' = \bar z s' = \bar z z c, \tag 3$

where we have made use of (2); now assuming $z \ne 0$ we may write

$z = re^{i\theta}, \tag 4$

whence

$0 < \bar z z = r^2 \in \Bbb R; \tag 5$

thus (3) takes the form

$c'' = r^2c; \tag 6$

we are given that $c(0) = 1$ and $s(0) = 0$; from this latter condition we deduce immidiately, *via* (1), that $c'(0) = 0$ and now we have a complete set of initial conditions for the second-order equation (3); since $r^2 > 0$ we know that the solutions to (3) will be linear combinations of $e^{rt}$ and $e^{-rt}$ with $r = \sqrt{\bar z z} > 0$; that $c(0) = 1$ and $c(0) = 0$ implies that this linear combination is in fact

$c(t) = \cosh rt ; \tag{7}$

from  (1) and (7) we immediately infer that

$s(t) = \dfrac{1}{\bar z} c'(t) = r^{-1}e^{i\theta} (\cosh rt)' = r^{-1}e^{i\theta}(r \sinh rt) = e^{i\theta} \sinh rt. \tag{8}$

Answer (score 0):

If we write $z = re^{i\theta}$, the solution is straightforwardly
$$
c = \cosh rt, \\
s =  e^{i\theta}\sinh rt, 
$$
which is easily generalized to non-constant $z$, only as long as the complex phase, $\theta$, is constant.

Comment: I'd like to see your generalization to $r(t)$ non-constant!

Comment: @RobertLewis It's not terribly interesting I'm afraid: it's just the standard replacing $rt$ by the integral of $r$ from $t=0$ to $t$.